# iOS: How to create a scrollable UIStackView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

[image: I am trying to recreate this]

How can i create something like this? I believe the labels should be buttons because i would like to click on them and then they would take me to another UIViewController.

But how can i make a stackView scrollable or this is not even a stackView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to adopt `UICollectionView` insted of StackView?

I think it could support this approach better than StackViews

Answer (score 1):

stackView doesn't scroll, You need to make either a horizontal scroll view with stackview in it Or The best approach is to use UICollectionView for this.
You will then write code for navigation in didSelectItemAt method of UICollectionViewDelegate.